# How do I work simultaneously on a project from two or more machines in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, collaboration

I have a team of 3 developers. We are working on a single project in Visual Studio 2010 from different locations.

How do I basically collaborate with the team mates so that all of us can work on the project simultaneously keeping everything in sync.

What tools will be required and how do I implement those tools for my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Team Foundation Version Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181237%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) (with [ankhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) or [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)).
- [Git](http://git-scm.com/) (the best IMHO, has [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) and a great "free colaborative repository", [GitHub](https://github.com/)).
- [plasticscm](http://www.plasticscm.com/) (has integration with VisualStudio, free for up to 15 developers).
- [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) (with optional [TortoiseHg](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TortoiseHg)).

Or just take a look at [here](http://www.software-pointers.com/en-configuration-tools.html).

TFS is good for beginners (SCM for dummies, based on locks, point-and-click interface, well integrated to Visual Studio - it is **the** official Microsoft SCM tool).

SVN is a good middle ground (avoids locking, centralized repository, good client GUIs).

But if you really want to use a state-of-art, distributed SCM tool, choose one of the last 3.

Regarding plasticscm, it seems to be a very nice solution - does SCM the right way, but has an astounding Visual Studio integration, like no other tool has (with the exception of TFS, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Best bet would be some type of source control

SVN is a quality, free solution, that will allow you all to connect to a single code repository.

http://subversion.tigris.org/

You can also use a free SVN server to get up and running quickly, like VisualSVN

http://www.visualsvn.com/

There are [many Visual Studio plugins](http://www.google.com/search?&q=visual+studio+SVN+integration) out there for SVN if you don't want to manage files from your folder structure

Answer (score 1):

Any source control provider with Visual Studio support will do.

On the expensive side is TFS, but it's got the most/best Visual Studio integration.

On the free side, you could set up a free ProjectLocker SVN repository (or just use your own) and connect to it from Visual Sutdio using AnkhSVN.

Answer (score 1):

You need a version control system. There are many of them, and many offers for free usage.
One example is Subversion, which is free, and and works with a central server, called repository. You can use an older machine as a server for the repository, even an older laptop is fine, for the team size you mention.

Here is a link to the [installer for the repository](http://svn1clicksetup.tigris.org/).

Then, each one of your development machines need a client for synchronising the source code. Here, [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is a popular option. There are even tools for synchronising from within Visual Studio. Google for VisualSVN and Ankhsvn.

Answer (score 0):

Use a version controlling tool, like SVN, and a plug-in for Visual Studio, like AnkhSVN.

Answer (score 0):

If you use svn, mercurial, or some of the other open source source code control techniques be aware that binaries and object files can be ignored.  Also you may have to deal with assemblies.  Make sure everyone on the project has access to the certificate or strong name file and its probably dangerous to keep it in svn without password protection.

Finally you should update first, and commit only after verifying that there are no bugs.  Make sure you make a zip of your entire project often and place it in a safe place just in case.  Also always separate the production from the development work.  :)