# how can I collaborate code with my partner in Visual Studio environment?

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn

Me and my friend want to work on a code together at the same time for our project.
We develop in Visual Studio 2010 environment.

I know I need something called `SVN client`, SVNTortoise, maybe `Git`..
I watched and read several guides on how should I install it, and I still dont have a clue how its all comes together .. and how can I `commit` and `update`?

I would love to have any input on what do I need, how do I do that and how much it costs

(some details :  we will have about 6 months of developments, we do need to integrate with some google APIs so I dont know if its possible to have it on my local drive..)

Comment: You didn't mention Mercurial but there's nice tutorial comparing it to SVN at http://hginit.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Version Control in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609483/version-control-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Source Code Management (SCM) system.

There are many available.  Subversion is one choice.  Git is another.  Mercurial is yet another.  Git and Mercurial are similar in that they're distributed.  Subversion is centralized.  Each model has advantages and disadvantages.

The tools you mention such as TortoiseSVN is just a graphical way of interacting with Subversion rather than at the command-line.  There's also TortoiseGit and there's also plugins for Visual Studio that allow you to do it from within Visual Studio.

It's pretty obvious you have no experience in this area.  This is not something into which you need to jump without some study.  If you don't understand what you're doing with these tools, you'll just get frustrated and possibly lose code by using them improperly.  Additionally, setting up your own shared server is not a minor task.  You probably want to consider using github, source forge or the like.

You need to do some reading on git and decide if it's the right tool for you.  Then do some reading on Subversion as a comparison, since it's centralized as opposed to git's distributed nature.

I would advise you to learn git - slowly.  Not only will you be learning a distributed tool, but you'll be learning the most popular one, with the best community support and most active development.  However, I'm certainly not going to pretend that it's not going to take some study.  If you've never used an SCM before, the concepts involved can be quite confusing.  Watch all the "git basics" tutorials you can, and read all the introductory material you can.  In particular, refer to [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book), an excellent book.